# window.scroll() doesn't work in jQuery mobile after navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and window.scroll() event is not working.

**Scenario is as follows**

$(window).scroll(function(){console.log("scroll event")}); is initialize on document ready. If I scroll the main page above event gets triggered, I can see the statement "scroll event" in console.

If I navigate to other page by clicking on a button with href="#nextPageID", navigate back to main page, and try to scroll, scroll event doesn't get triggered.

Could you please let me know the reason for this kind of behaviour.

Thanks, Vijay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in jQuery 1.4.x, Reference link is here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8250, this might help some one who is in the similar position.